# default parameter routing changes the reference of an image in asp.net mvc 4.51

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two controllers. I copied one action from one controller (called `Biz1Controller`) to the other (called `Biz2Controler`). The only change I made is that in one action I have to state the parameter in the query string, and in the other I rely on the automatic route to take the parameter (id).

First action signature:

```
public ActionResult Page(int BizId)
```

Second action signature:

```
public ActionResult Page(int id)
```

Other than that everything is exactly the same, including the view.

However, the view loads some image:

```
<div style="background-image: url('@Model.PathToFG');"></div>
```

Now, the View Source of chrome shows that everything is just the same, I get this line of script:

```
<div style="background-image: url('../Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg');"></div>
```

However, for the first controller which is called this way:

> localhost:19417/Biz1/Page?BizId=10

I get the image correctly.

and for the second controller called this way:

> localhost:19417/Biz2/Page/10

I get the following error in the browser's console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:19417/Biz2/Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg

i.e., for some reason the controller (`Biz2`) now appears as part of the image path, which is incorrect and should be: http://localhost:19417/Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg

if I call the action this way:

> localhost:19417/Biz2/Page?id=10

I get the image. How does the browser even aware to this? I can't tell.

What is going on? this is not as I expected. What should I do so that this call

> localhost:19417/Biz2/Page/10

will result in the correct reference to the image?

Answer (score 0):

Add these to the routes in your configuration file

```
routes.MapRoute(
            ....
                new { controller = "Biz2", action = "Page", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on. Maybe @NZeta520 is the right direction to check. However, instead of relative path `../Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg` I used absolute path `/Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how relative path works,

explanation using `file-folder` analogy,

for url `localhost:19417/Biz1/Page?BizId=10`, your current folder is `Biz1` and current file is `Page`, query string doesn't matter.

now when a relative path, `../Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg` is applied to the current url, `..` goes to the previous folder which is `localhost:19417` then appends the rest of the path forming `localhost:19417/Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg`

interestingly for url `localhost:19417/Biz2/Page/10`, your current folder is `Page` and current file is `10`. So when relative path `../Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg` is applied, `..` goes to the previous folder which is `localhost:19417/Biz2` then appends the rest of the path forming `localhost:19417/Biz2/Images/FgResized/FG-10000001.jpg` which is the unintended one.

hope this helps.